# i have an error when change browser url with pushState() in angular application

Tags: angularjs, pushstate

I need to change browser URL when bootstrap modal opened in angularJs application , I used `pushState()` function, the url has changed, but it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope: infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.Aborting!
    Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [
        ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],
        ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],
        ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],
        ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"],
        ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 12; oldVal: 11"]
    ] 
    http: //errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…2fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2012%3B%20oldVal%3A%2011%22%5D%5D angular-1.2.13.js:78
    (anonymous function) angular-1.2.13.js:78
    Scope.$digest angular-1.2.13.js:11937
    (anonymous function) angular-1.2.13.js:12084
    completeOutstandingRequest angular-1.2.13.js:4144
    (anonymous function)
```

Comment: please, clarify your question. add the code that thrown the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with the `$location` service in angular.  It was just fixed in the newest release of Angular 1.3.0-beta.20, on 8/27/2014.  See issue [3924](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3924) and the duplicate [6976](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6976), which was credited to the fix.

Documentation of a temporary fix was made by the angular-ui team: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/562#issuecomment-31623003

> The problem is caused because Angular isn't synchronously notified of changes to the browser's url, and trusts its cached version of the url inside  $browser.url() . Since  $browser.url()  as a getter is idempotent, it keeps returning the true url without updating its internal record of what the url is.
>
> To verify that this is true, add this line in the provided test just after the  window.history.replaceState  line, and the test will pass:  angular.element($window).triggerHandler('popstate');
>
> This issue could be easily fixed with one line inside of  $browser , by resetting  lastBrowserUrl  inside the  url  getter:  lastBrowserUrl = newLocation || location.href.replace(/%27/g,"'");  But this could cause unwanted side effects.